# different output between command execution and subprocess.run

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I am getting two different output for same command when i am trying to execute command from command line manual and from python.

I am trying to run one command **python --version** from linux to window over ssh from command line and python. but observed two different output.
following code i am using to call ssh_command from python:

```
 result = subprocess.run(ssh_command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

 return_results = str(result.stdout.decode())
```

Getting below result in python:

[?25l[2J[m[H+++++++

[2;1H]0;C:\windows\system32\conhost.exe[?25hpytest 7.4.4

+++++++

But proper result when i trying execution from command line:

+++++++

pytest 7.4.4

+++++++

Comment: `[?25l[2J[m[H` is terminal control characters -- moving the cursor around, changing color, and so forth. The "proper result" presumably _does_ do some kind of colorization, right? You're seeing the character sequences that, when received by the terminal, tells it to do that.

Comment: The rest of what you're seeing is Windows just being badly behaved. On decent platforms, when you run `sh -c 'something'` (as ssh does when it's passed a command to run remotely on its command line), `sh` gets out of the way and doesn't write anything to stdout or stderr -- no prompt, to terminal control sequences, etc -- but Windows is Windows; it's never cared about the rest of the world's conventions.

Comment: BTW, if you wanted to allow other people to reproduce the problem, you would include the way `ssh_command` is formed. (BTW, you're starting on Linux, it's better practice to have `ssh_command` to be a _list_, not a string, and to have `shell=False` -- but that's unlikely to be a factor in the immediate problem).

Answer (score -1):

It's cause of the shell param, the artefacts you're seeing are from the prompt. The output is as expected if you run it in non-shell mode:

```
>>> res = subprocess.run(["python", "--version"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> res.stdout.decode()
'Python 3.7.13\n'
```

Note that here you must use a sequence as `args` instead of a string like `python --version`:

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
> of program arguments. [...] If passing a single string, either shell
> must be True (see below) or else the string must simply name the program
> to be executed without specifying any arguments. [[ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)]

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488/13171163

Comment: This is all good advice in general, but unfortunately, the artifacts the OP needs go be rid of are from the _remote_ shell, not the local one -- which is to say, the shell started by sshd on the remote (Windows-based) server, not the shell started by Python on the local (Linux-based) host.